# Powershell DSC xWebsite is failing

Tags: powershell, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, dsc

I am trying to use the xWebsite resource in powershell DSC but it keeps failing to Set-TargetResource.  the error is

```
PowerShell provider MSFT_xWebsite  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message:  
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
```

The resource looks like

```
    WindowsFeature IIS 
{ 
  Ensure = “Present” 
  Name   = “Web-Server” 
} 
    xWebsite Website
{
    Ensure       = "Present"
    Name         = "Website"
    PhysicalPath = "E:\www\site"
    State        = "Started"
    BindingInfo  = MSFT_xWebBindingInformation 
    {
        Protocol = 'HTTP'
        Port     = 7777
        HostName = '*'
    }

    DependsOn    = "[WindowsFeature]IIS"
}
```

I just copied it from one of the DSC examples, and initially it did not return the above error.  I do not know what changed, but now it cannot create the website on subsequent runs.  There is not a lot of troubleshooting content on DSC yet either, and I am hoping that someone else has run into this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding the initial run not returning an error

[This may be related to this bug.](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/951294/dsc-msft-dsclocalconfigurationmanager-cim-classs-performrequiredconfigurationchecks-sometimes-returns-without-doing-any-work)

### Regarding the error itself

Let's check the obvious stuff first:

1. All components of the `PhysicalPath` must exist; the resource won't create any of those paths. So use a `File` resource to create them if needed then make `xWebsite` depend on it.
2. Make sure a different web site is not using the port.
3. You show a `DependsOn` but don't show the rest of your configuration. Make sure that you're actually specifying a `WindowsFeature` resource in your config for it to depend on.

### If those don't help

Post the rest of your config (if there is more).

Check out the [xDscDiagnostics](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xDscDiagnostics-PowerShell-abb6bcaa) module in the DSC Resource Kit. It's not a resource, it's 2 functions that help you turn on the diagnostic and debug logs for DSC and then retrieve the events related to a specific run. This should help you figure out the actual underlying error.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I edited my post to show that I did indeed have the WindowsFeature there.  I dont know if this will help anyone who sees this, but I manually added a site to IIS with the same properties and from then on running the DSC configuration would not give that error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into problems trying to use the xWebsite resource on Windows Server 2008 R2 too. Then I noticed that at the bottom of the [documentation page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be), it says:

> Verified on the following platforms
>
> Windows Server 2012:  Yes
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2: No

I ended up debugging through the module code outside of DSC. I found that there were several bits that didn't work on 2008R2, and so had to create my own version of the module that worked on that operating system.

Sorry - no easy fix!